# Changing button's text and color inside AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing two actions when the callback of my AJAX call is completed:

1. Display a PNotification using the `notification()` function
2. Change the button by removing a class, adding a class, and replacing the text (self-explanatory in the `changeButton()` function).

   ```
   $('.btn-material-yellow-600').click(function(){
       if($(this).text().trim() == "Add Me!") {
           $.ajax({
               type: 'post',
               url: '{{ URL('schedulizer/add') }}',
               data: {
                   "class": ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
                   _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
               },
               dataType: 'json'
           }).done(function(data){
               notification('Added', 'success');
               changeButton(
                   $(this),
                   'btn-material-yellow-600',
                   'btn-danger',
                   '\nRemove Me!'
               );
           });
           return false;
       }
   ```

This is `changeButton`:

```
    function changeButton(button, remove, add, text) {
        button.removeClass(remove);
        button.addClass(add);
        button.text(text);
    }
```

What works:

The notification works just fine

What doesn't work:

The `changeButton()` does not work. I am pretty sure the reason the changing of the button doesn't work is because I use `$(this)` inside the callback, when I have to call something else.. or pass in another variable..

Not quite sure.. Since I am so newb to JS :/

Checking the console, I do not see any errors reported.

Comment: Post the function definition for `changeButton()`.  Also console.log(this) to make sure it points to the right element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with `$(this)`

What should work is:

```
$('.btn-material-yellow-600').click(function(){
    var $element = $(this);
    if($element.text().trim() == "Add Me!") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '{{ URL('schedulizer/add') }}',
            data: {
                "class": ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            notification('Added', 'success');
            changeButton(
                $element,
                'btn-material-yellow-600',
                'btn-danger',
                '\nRemove Me!'
            );
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Reasoning is that `this` only applies to the element directly in the click handler. Inside the ajax callback `this` refers to the context of the callback, which will be `window`.

Comment: This one worked! Is this in any danger of having the var in global scope?

Comment: actually inside the callback `this` does have context... it's the xhr settings object

Comment: No, when a variable is declared with `var`, the scope is the containing function (not the block as with many other languages). As an aside, with ES6 the `let` keyword lets you have block scoping.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from declaring variable referencing `this` outside of the ajax you can also use the `context` option to tell the callbacks what `this` is

```
$.ajax({
   context: this, // assigns what `this` is in callbacks
   type: 'post',
  ....
}).done(function(data){
    notification('Added', 'success');
    changeButton(
        $(this), 
        'btn-material-yellow-600',
        'btn-danger',
        '\nRemove Me!'
    );
});
```

Comment: Is this method better than Andy's method? I can be totally wrong, but he prevents the var from being in a global scope (which is less dangerous I think..?)

Comment: there isn't really one better than the other. Any time a `var` is declared inside a function it is only local to that function.

Answer (score 1):

yes! you're right ! and its simple solution!

```
    $('.btn-material-yellow-600').click(function(){

   var localThis = $(this);

        if($(this).text().trim() == "Add Me!") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '{{ URL('schedulizer/add') }}',
                data: {
                    "class": ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"],
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
                notification('Added', 'success');
                changeButton(
                    localThis,
                    'btn-material-yellow-600',
                    'btn-danger',
                    '\nRemove Me!'
                );
            });
            return fa
```

Comment: avoid putting `localThis` in global scope though!

Comment: I attempted this myself, but I am receiving a `button.removeClass is not a function`

Comment: sorry! @AndyNewman is right ! i  forget to use "var" before localThis!

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refer to something else due to closure in callback where `this` is the xhr settings object. Instead you can define variable before your ajax block and use them inside the callback function.

```
//Before Ajax block
var elem = $(this);
```

And in your callback:

```
changeButton(
            elem,
            'btn-material-yellow-600',
            'btn-danger',
            '\nRemove Me!'
        );
```

Comment: correct about `this` ... but not really because of asynchronous, it's due to closure in callback where `this` is the xhr settings object

Comment: It was what I ever said to myself, thanks I'll edit that

Comment: *It was what I ever said to myself.*

Seems to sum up programming.

Comment: I can't handle this "Seems to sum up programming", could you translate it bro ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is due to the **this**

The other answers have code which will work. Thought I could explain a little about the **this**

**this** refers to the context. Therefore when ever it is used you should see who the owner of method/function is and **this** will refer to that object/variable.

In your case **this** refer to the AJAX object that is created for the request.

## Solutions:

Store the **this** in a different variable before the $.ajax and use that variable in **done**
- e.g.

```
 var that = this;
 ...
 .done(function(){
    changeButton(that, ...) 
 })
```

### OR

If you would like to continue to use the **this**, **bind** the **done** function to the parent **this**

```
.done(function(){
    changeButton(this, ...)  
}).bind(this)
```